# Android connect to Mysql database tutorial

Tags: android, mysql

Does anybody know a complete and working tutorial about how to retrieve data from MYSQL and display it in Android? I'm asking this because all the tutorials I found are older than API 22 and from API 22 the HttpClient is deprecated. And I'm a new Android Developer so I can't write any code on my own. :)

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient

- Interface for an HTTP client. HTTP clients encapsulate a smorgasbord of objects required to execute HTTP requests while handling cookies, authentication, connection management, and other features. Thread safety of HTTP clients depends on the implementation and configuration of the specific client.
- This interface was deprecated in API level 22.
  Please use openConnection() instead.
- Apache HTTP client has fewer bugs on Eclair and Froyo. It is the best choice for these releases.

For Gingerbread and better, HttpURLConnection is the best choice. Its simple API and small size makes it great fit for Android. Transparent compression and response caching reduce network use, improve speed and save battery. New applications should use HttpURLConnection; it is where we will be spending our energy going forward.

- Please visit this webpage for further details.
  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html
- An URLConnection for HTTP (RFC 2616) used to send and receive data over the web. Data may be of any type and length. This class may be used to send and receive streaming data whose length is not known in advance.
- Uses of this class follow a pattern:
- Obtain a new HttpURLConnection by calling URL.openConnection() and casting the result to HttpURLConnection.
- Read the response. Response headers typically include metadata such as the response body's content type and length, modified dates and session cookies. The response body may be read from the stream returned by getInputStream(). If the response has no body, that method returns an empty stream.
- For example, to retrieve the webpage at http://www.android.com/:

  URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)           url.openConnection();
  try {
   InputStream in = new        BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   readStream(in);
   finally {
   urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
  }
- Please visit this webpage for further details.
- http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html
- urlconnection tutorials, can visit this websites
  +http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html
  +http://javatechig.com/android/android-networking-tutorial